# Batch to call Java main class

Tags: java, batch-file

I am getting an error for below batch file.

```
cls
set classpath=C:\Program^ Files\salesforce.com\Data^ Loader\dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar
set mainclass=com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner
set confdir=C:\Program^ Files\salesforce.com\Data^ Loader\Bkp\

if [%1]==[]  goto error

call java -cp %classpath% -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%confdir% %mainclass% process.name=Product_vod__c sfdc.extractionSOQL="SELECT 

Id,name FROM Product_vod__c where Id in %1"
goto end

:error
echo Error: missing date argument (must be in 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ' format)
:end
```

**Error**

```
Could not find or load main class Files\salesforce.com\Data
```

Can someone please let me know the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an unescaped `Program Files` somewhere in your classpath and its space breaks the classpath argument : the classpath stops at `Program` and java parses the following `Files\salesforce.com\Data` as the class it should execute.

You should enclose classpath fragments containing spaces with double-quotes.

Comment: But carot sign is there to escape the space in 'Program Files'. You mean carot is not working?

Comment: Do you maybe mean a backslash (`\ `) ? Because a [Caret sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) wouldn't work neither in batch nor in java pathes. Anyway you've got to escape it for both languages : `\ ` would be understood by java (and unix), however batch won't understand it (since backslashes are path separators) and will provide java with two different parameters.

Comment: Well actually you've only got to escape it for batch, java won't mind having spaces in its classpath since it splits it around `;` (under windows) or `:` (under unix). Anyway what I said still stands, use double-quotes around path fragments that include spaces (either around the whole file path or only the directory containing the space)

Comment: @SFDC_Learner I just saw caret sign can indeed be used to escape characters in batch, I don't know why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner, the `^` sign works, but at a point where it is not needed: the variable assignment (`set`); as soon as you expand your variable like `%classpath%`, the _space_  appears again and breaks up the command line; the only solution for this is to use double-quotes like `"%classpath%"`...